# Backup the system, upgrade the os version and restore backup.. the whole process?

Tags: upgrade, 15.04, backup, restore, deja-dup

I'm using Ubunutu 15.04 at the moment and I want to upgrade it to 16.04 without losing any of my data(I guess it means home directory).

I found a resource like [this](https://gist.github.com/blakethepatton/196e593999e4e8630d364bad3a076deb) and think of using it but, first, I need to back up my system.

I want to use System Settings > Backups (Deja-Dup) to backup my stuff. But, I dont know the process after this. If I manage to upgrade my system successfully to 16.04, how will I restore my stuff?

- Firstly, do you think the link above is good for upgrading my system?
- Should I use an external drive to store my backup?
- I actually already backed up my things to `home/deja-dup` directory. If I copy it to external drive, will it work?
- I have a second account at the moment. Should I back it up to another folder in the hard drive and follow the same steps as my main account when restoring it?

If someone explains the whole process step by step I will be grateful.

Comment: Though the procedure mentioned in the link might work, if you are going to backup all the users' data anyway you may as well reinstall 16.04 from scratch, or 18.04 for that matter.

Comment: Apologies: I meant to say "install 16.04", not "reinstall 16.04".

Comment: Support for Ubuntu 15.04 ended years ago. The upgrade path you propose is untested and unsupported here (don't do it!). You are asking for support with releases and actions that we explicitly don't support. The best answer you will get there is to preserve all your data onto an external media, then clean-install a supported release of Ubuntu. The best backup is one you **know** how to restore. Play with deja-dup until you do know, or choose a different method that you are more comfortable with.